# Facebook Share Links Script - Not Extracting Local IMG

Tags: php

In reference to this script shown on this page:
[facebook share links script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382138/facebook-share-links-script)

I got it to work just fine, but it doesn't display any images that are local. An example would be:

`img src="/path/to/image.jpg" alt=""`

It also doesn't "grab" images that are using some sort of php image script. An example would be:

`img src="/getimage.php?path/to/image.jpg&w=500" alt=""`

Does anyone know how to fix these problems? I've tried adding the `$url` string in front but that didn't work at all. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Source script is [here](http://www.99points.info/2010/07/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with-jquery-ajax-php/).

Comment: You can try to solve it by using this : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, Normally the image should be a in a <meta>

Comment: Thanks Awea, but that didn't help any. I can't find anyone who knows how to fix this. I've really got to learn PHP...

Comment: I didn't think the problem come from PHP You need to have correct meta to share on facebook with some texts/images

Comment: I'm not sharing anything on Facebook though Awea. It is a php script that mimics how Facebook fetches the URL, photo and description from websites when you post a link. :) Thanks for trying to help though, I do appreciate it. :)

Comment: You're welcome sorry for my wrong advice :)